# How to get nested property using dig method

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get a property value from a nested property but it is returning nothing.

When I run `log.info record['metadata']`, I got the following output:

```
bang_1            | 2020-01-20 16:47:28 +0000 [info]: #0  body_size="16" collector_ip="172.22.0.1" collector_timestamp=1579538848944 name="default" version="1.0.0"
```

So I ran `log.info record.dig('metadata').class` to check the class:

```
bang_1            | 2020-01-20 16:47:28 +0000 [info]: #0 Hash
```

How can I get the value of property `name`? I'm trying to execute the following code but I got an `NilClass`.

```
log.info record.dig('metadata', 'name')
log.info record.dig('metadata', 'name').class
```

```rb
record = {
  'xx': 1
}
record['metadata'] = {
  'name': 'default'  
}

puts record
puts record['metadata']

# {:xx=>1, "metadata"=>{:name=>"default"}}
#.{:name=>"default"}
```

Comment: Can you please fire up `irb`, call `puts record["metadata"]`, and then update your question to include the output (bonus points for formatting it nicely)? Right now we're left guessing as to the content.

Comment: My bad, first time running Ruby and it's dockerized. Sorry if it's mal formatting. Check the edit with `puts` result.

Comment: @spickermann yes, I did: `undefined method `name'`

Comment: @spickermann it worked using `record.dig('metadata', :name)`. What's the difference?

Comment: Please don't use "edit" or "updated" type tags when adding information to your question or answers. Instead incorporate the new information into the text as if it was there to begin with. We can tell what changed if we need to. See "[Should “Edit:” in edits be discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255644/128421)"
"[Why is writing an “Update” section in an SO question frowned upon?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368283/128421)"
"[Are Edit: and Update: notes in posts encouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270775/128421)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these lines

```
record['metadata'] = {
  'name': 'default'  
}
```

the syntax `'name':` stores the value `'default'` with the symbolized key `:name` (not the string key `name`). Therefore you need to read that value like this:

```
record.dig('metadata', :name)
```

When you want to avoid using a symbolized key then you can use the other hash syntax when creating the hash:

```
record['metadata'] = {
  'name' => 'default'  
}
```

Comment: Is possible to use a string `name` instead of `:name`? Just curious

Comment: @placplacboom Yeah, just use `'name' => 'default'` instead of `'name': 'default'` which would be the same as `name: 'default'` or `:name => 'default'`.